# WSO2 Governance Registry : - Active Directory Users are not able to login after giving login permissions

Tags: active-directory, wso2

I have successfully configured wso2 Governance registry product with our Active Directory Server and able to see all configured users in users list in management console.However after giving login permissions to AD users , they are not able to login. Any specific attribute I need to provide for that. Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: Any exceptions noticed?

Comment: It didn't give any exceptions in logs ,it was a warning stating failed Administrator Login Attempt.  Just an JS pop up stating Login Check failed. Any input I need to post here ? Please help.

Comment: Can you try the following and see. comment the "UserDNPattern" property in the user-mgt.xml restart the server and try to login. By giving login permission to the user i assume you mean that you assigned a role with login permission to the user.

Comment: @pulasthi :- Thanks a ton...It worked by commenting userDNPattern prop. A few surprising thing to observe here , I did not provide any userDNPattern lest kept it blank. One , it gives an error UserRealmProxy - > UserStoreException - wso2.com:389 , Second it does not give any exception stack trace nor halts product functioning. Any clue for this.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment out the "userDNPattern" attribute. let me explain a bit more. This property is used to improve performance so that when searching for a user in the LDAP structure this particular area is looked at.rather than going through the whole area defined in the "UserSearchBase" property. So commenting out the "userDNPattern" will not have any harm other than performance. If you properly define "userDNPattern" there should be no problem. i believe it is not defined properly according to your LDAP structure in AD.

Comment: :- I got purpose of userDNPattern prop here , I have been following up with AD team here to get userDNPattern string , meanwhile I do have userSearchBase string , can we extract userDNPattern value out of it anyhow ? not that versed with AD stuff...:(

Comment: And you are correct..performance is damn slow ,also please take above exception in consideration either ,although it does not hinder anyways , yet possibly be causing slowness of system..thanks in advance

Comment: yes a part of the string needed can be taken from the userSearchBase string, But without knowladge of your AD structure i am not able to tell the correct string. Your AD team should be able to give a quick answer for this. Do not leave the userDNPattern as empty comment it out if you are not using it.

Comment: Initially I had configured AD through management console where in it was taking userDNPattern prop value with some value by default , later I did changes in user-mgmt.xml file and commented out userDNPattern prop. Still performance is damn slow with one common error in background UserRealmProxy - > org.wso2.carbon.user.store.UserStoreException: wso2.com:389